# Conversion to expression in base 17 with particular needs

Tags: number-representation, number-bases, output-formatting

So, I am trying to write a function that takes a number between 0 and 1 in base 10 as input and gives a list of its decimal figures in it's expression in base 17. For example, $f(0.5)= \lbrace 8,8,8,8,8,\ldots\rbrace$. My function in particular needs to provide the output in a certain manner. For instance, $f(1/17)=\lbrace 0,16,16,16,16,\ldots\rbrace$ BUT $f(2/17)=\lbrace 2,0,0,\ldots\rbrace$.

The function I have writen so far is as follows:

```
Base17[t_] := Block[{digitsandexponent, listofdigits, n, m},
  digitsandexponent = RealDigits[N[t], 17];
  listofdigits = digitsandexponent[[1]];
  m = digitsandexponent[[2]];
  n = 0;
  If[m > n,
   (*the only considered case in which this could happen is if t=1*)
   listofdigits = {16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16},
   
   (*if it's not one, add the decimal 0's to the front*)
   While[n < -m,
    PrependTo[listofdigits, 0];
    n = n + 1]
   ];
  
  If[AnyTrue[listofdigits, OddQ], 
   If[Length[Position[listofdigits, _Integer?OddQ]] > 1,
    (*if there's more than one odd number, do nothing*)
     listofdigits = listofdigits,
    
    
    (*if there's exactly one odd number and after that it is all \
16's, add one to the odd number and turn the 16's into 0's*)
    If[listofdigits[[Position[listofdigits, _Integer?OddQ][[1, 1]] + 
          1 ;;  ]] == 
      Table[16, {i, Position[listofdigits, _Integer?OddQ][[1, 1]] + 1,
         Length[listofdigits]}],
     listofdigits[[Position[listofdigits, _Integer?OddQ][[1, 1]] + 1 ;;
          Length[listofdigits]]] = 
      Table[0, {i, Position[listofdigits, _Integer?OddQ][[1, 1]] + 1, 
        Length[listofdigits]}];
     listofdigits[[Position[listofdigits, _Integer?OddQ][[1, 1]]]] = 
      listofdigits[[Position[listofdigits, _Integer?OddQ][[1, 1]]]] + 
       1];
    
    
    (*if there's exactly one odd number and after that it is all 0's, 
    substract one to the odd number and turn the 0's into 16's*)
    If[listofdigits[[Position[listofdigits, _Integer?OddQ][[1, 1]] + 
          1 ;; Length[listofdigits]]] == 
      Table[0, {i, Position[listofdigits, _Integer?OddQ][[1, 1]] + 1, 
        Length[listofdigits]}],
     listofdigits[[Position[listofdigits, _Integer?OddQ][[1, 1]] + 1 ;;
          Length[listofdigits]]] = 
      Table[16, {i, Position[listofdigits, _Integer?OddQ][[1, 1]] + 1,
         Length[listofdigits]}];
     listofdigits[[Position[listofdigits, _Integer?OddQ][[1, 1]]]] = 
      listofdigits[[Position[listofdigits, _Integer?OddQ][[1, 1]]]] - 
       1];
    ]
   ];
  
  Return[listofdigits]
  ]
```

In general it works well, but it returns some errors. For example, for $t=22718/1419857$, it produces good output but with the next errors:

```
Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist.

Part::span: 1+{}[[1,1]];;14 is not a valid Span specification. A Span specification should be 1, 2, or 3 machine-sized integers separated by ;;. (Any of the integers can be omitted or replaced with All.)

Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist.

Table::iterb: Iterator {i,1+{}[[1,1]],14} does not have appropriate bounds.

Table::iterb: Iterator {i,1+{}[[1,1]],14} does not have appropriate bounds.
```

However, for $t=22717/1419857$ it produces no errors.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens? Thank you for your time!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can do:

```
base17[t_] := Replace[
    RealDigits[N[t, 15], 17, Automatic, -1][[1]],
    {
    {b___,i_?OddQ,r : 0 ...} :>{b,i-1, Splice[ConstantArray[16,Length[{r}]]]},
    {b___,i_?OddQ,r : 16 ...} :> {b,i+1,  Splice[ConstantArray[0,Length[{r}]]]}
    }
]
```

Your examples:

```
base17[22717/1419857]
base17[22718/1419857]
```

> {0, 4, 10, 10, 4, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16}

> {0, 4, 10, 10, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

Comment: That works awesomely well, and way much cleaner than mine! It only has the issue that 0 and 1 have the same output, but a simple If solves that matter. Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually, I have found something with the behaviour of that function that I do not really know how to solve in a neat way. For $t=10/17+9/17^2$, it produces output {10,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} instead of {10,8,16,16,16...}.  Any suggestion of a neat code for that matter?

Comment: @juanzaragoza long do you want the lists to be? Should it always have length 13?

Comment: not really, I just felt that 13 numbers would be enough precision to give a flavour of what the infinite expression would be like.

Comment: @juanzaragoza I modified my answer to use extended precision instead. See if that works better.